# Sum of column in Generated Table

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, mysql

I'm trying to get sum of data in one colum in Generated HTML table.

The table is getting yt_id from MySQL and use JSON to get data from YT Api (the the table is autogenerated)

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<?php
include_once('db.php');

$result = mysql_query("select * from yt_data");


echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Views</th>
<th>Likes</th>
</tr>";

while($r=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{    
   $yt_id=$r["yt_id"];

   $video_ID = $yt_id;
$JSON = file_get_contents("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/{$video_ID}?v=2&alt=json");
$JSON_Data = json_decode($JSON);
$views = $JSON_Data->{'entry'}->{'yt$statistics'}->{'viewCount'};
$likes = $JSON_Data->{'entry'}->{'yt$rating'}->{'numLikes'};


  echo "<tr id='countit'>";
  echo "<td>" . $yt_id . "</td>";
  echo "<td class='count-me'>" . $views . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $likes . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";



}

echo "</table>";
?>
</html>
```

I have tried to get sum using this code but I'm getting just NaN:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var tds = document.getElementById('countit').getElementsByTagName('td');
var sum = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < tds.length; i ++) {
if(tds[i].className == 'count-me') {
sum += isNaN(tds[i].innerHTML) ? 0 : parseInt(tds[i].innerHTML);
}
}
document.getElementById('countit').innerHTML += '<tr><td>' + sum + '</td><td>total</td></tr>';
</script>
```

Any idea how to make this to work?

Edit 1: I have removed the table id and now works good. But I want to sum all data in column so all data of $views. Any idea How to do this?
I'm using this but always is getting just value of first one

```
var tds = document.getElementById('countit').getElementsByTagName('td');
var sum = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < tds.length; i ++) {
    if(tds[i].className == 'count-me') {
        sum += isNaN(tds[i].innerHTML) ? 0 : parseInt(tds[i].innerHTML);
    }
}
document.getElementById('countit').innerHTML += '<tr><td>' + sum + '</td><td>total</td></tr>';
```

Comment: Could you post the generated markup instead of the php? It works fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Z8wjL/3/)

Comment: Did you place javascript bottom of the page. If it is not place it at bottom.

Comment: Yes I have place in the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

try with class selector

```
var tds = $('.countit td'); //using jquery
var tds = document.getElementsByClassName(countit).getElementsByTagName('td'); //using javascript
```

instead of

```
var tds = document.getElementById('countit').getElementsByTagName('td');
```

**OR**

```
var sum = 0;
$.each($('.count-me'),function(i,v) {
    var $text=$(v).text();
    sum += isNaN($text) ? 0 : parseInt($text);

}

$('#countit').append('<tr><td>' + sum + '</td><td>total</td></tr>');
```

Comment: When I have tried this:  var tds = $('.countit td'); //using jquery  I've got again "Nan"  but when I have tried: var tds = document.getElementsByClassName(countit).getElementsByTagName('td'); //using javascript  now I'm not getting anything.

Comment: I have removed the table id and now works good. But I want to sum all data in column so all data of $views. Any idea How to do this?

Comment: if you are using the second method.. then you can add class `count-me` to al lthe `<td>` that you want to sum up

Comment: Yes I know it but in source code I have just this  echo "<td class='count-me'>" . $views . "</td>";     I'm not getting the data from MySQL but the table it's auto generated. Hope that you understand me. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop through the rows also.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
rows = document.getElementById('countit').getElementsByTagName('tr');
for(var j = 0; j < rows.length; j ++) {
  var tds = row[j].getElementsByTagName('td');
  var sum = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < tds.length; i ++) {
    if(tds[i].className == 'count-me') {
      sum += isNaN(tds[i].innerHTML) ? 0 : parseInt(tds[i].innerHTML);
    }
  }
}
document.getElementById('countit').innerHTML += '<tr><td>' + sum + '</td><td>total</td></tr>';
</script>
```

As a suggestion the table id and TR class name is same "countit". it is a bit confusing. Please change one value.

Comment: Yeah I have removed the table id and now works good. But I want to sum all data in column so all data of $views. Any idea How to do this?